# Inside Info on Dynamic Data

Tags: .net, asp.net, dynamic-data

This is a sister question to my other one here, not linked to because I'm not posting this to pull views of that.  I'm busy with my first dynamic data project and loving it, and, of course, I have a few challenges that I'd like to resolve and also maybe debug myself.  However, the framework is quite dense in terms of how what gets done once you get past dynamic controls.

I would appreciate pointers to some articles etc. that explain the foundations, how tables are scaffolded, what type of data source is used, how do I write custom components that do more than just be in the right place at the right time (I do love that though, convention over etc. yadda yadda).

I have often played with concepts like scaffolding for years, but it was always too much work outside of my requirements to be more than wishful thinking.  Now I have it delivered, almost cooked well done, and I think it's great, but so many resources out there only tell me how to use the provided 'tracks', and I still have no clue as to what goes on at the shunting yard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dynamic data on code plex:  Good resource, have lots of samples on doing things beyond the basics.
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Dynamic%20Data

Some samples include creating your own view using your own select statement.

Matt berseth - 
http://mattberseth.com/blog/dynamic_data/

Has some nice tutorials on again doing beyond the basics like creating a custom meta provider that allows you to change the default way your columns are named.

Stephen Naughton - 
http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/

Several great examples of going more in depth with DD such as globally shutting off foreign key from showing at all.

Craig Shoemaker also has some great examples and a book for about $10.  The book isn't heavily into the underpinnings though.

http://weblogs.asp.net/craigshoemaker/archive/tags/Dynamic+Data/default.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/rickandy/archive/2009/01/08/dynamic-data-faq.aspx - Great links to resources

http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-SP1/ - video's on DD...
http://forums.asp.net/1145.aspx - forums for dynamic data....

You may also want to get into resources on linq to sql or linq to EF if you aren't very familiar with these topics.  Knowing more about these topics and extending them will also add to your arsenal for DD.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, that's a great selection of reading for next week, when I get over the weekend's priority work and meetings.

Comment: No Problem. :) It's a list I have compiled while trying to learn and use DD.